# Safari 'find' does not focus on link after looking for a word

Tags: safari, shortcut

In Firefox I find very useful this feature:
 after looking for a word (`cmd+F`) it allows to quickly open a new page — if the string I was looking for was part of an  active link - just by pressing the *return* key.

Is there a way to get this effect in safari too?